# Recursive descent parser - dealing with closing brackets

Tags: java, parsing, recursive-descent

I'm trying to build a recursive descent parser that builds an AST as it goes. The language is fairly simple;

```
x >/</= y #x, y can be any letter/number, matched by regex.
```

Then, `AND/OR` with opening/closing brackets follow and everything repeats itself. The brackets are always where they should be, x/y are always valid.
My code:

```
private Node parseLogic(Node lhs) {
    String curr = token.curr();
    if (curr.equals("(")) { 
        leftCount++;
        token.progress(1);
        return parseExpression();
    }
    if (curr.equals("AND ")) { // we want to get the rhs expression so we have to reparse
        token.progress(1);
        Node rhs = parseExpression();
        return new And(lhs, rhs);
    }
    if (curr.equals("OR ")) { //same
        token.progress(1);
        Node rhs = parseExpression();
        return new Or(lhs, rhs);
    }
    if (curr.equals(")")){ 
        rightCount++;
        token.progress(1);
        if (leftCount == rightCount){
            return lhs;
        }
        return parseLogic(lhs);
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

private Node parseExpression(){
    String curr = token.curr();
    if (curr.equals("(")){
        leftCount++;
        token.progress(1);
        return parseExpression();
    }
    else if (exPatt.matcher(curr).matches()){ // if it matches an expression, go inside. if next is ), close it
        Node node = new Expression(curr);
        if (token.next().equals("AND ") || token.next().equals("OR ") ||
        token.next().equals("(") || token.next().equals(")")){
            token.progress(1);
            return parseLogic(node);
        }
        return node;
    }   
    return null;

}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parser parse = new Parser("amount > 50 AND ((row < 20 OR team > 30) AND (test < 40 OR you < 20)))");
    //Node node = parse.mainParser();
    Node node = parse.parseExpression();
    node.getExpression();
}
```

}

The code works great on examples such as

`amount > 50 OR (amount < 30 AND (test < 20 OR (test > 10 OR left < 10)))`

But fails in ones like

`amount > 50 AND ((row < 20 OR team > 30) AND (test < 40 OR you < 20)))`

Where the handling of the closed parentheses fails, and instead of having the second node be
`LHS = OR (row < 20, team > 30)`
`RHS = OR (test < 40, you <20)`
we get
`LHS = row < 20`
`RHS = AND (team > 30 OR (test <40, you <20))`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I think I fixed it. Keeping this up incase anyone else faces a recursive descent parser with an AST, as there aren't many SO questions on this topic.

Inside `parseLogic`, the and/ors instead of returning just the node, re-enter `parseLogic` with the new nodes. This is to basically check if the node is the left of any other logic node. if not, in the end, `lhs` is simply returned.

Comment: You should answer this question and accept it if you don't get a better one.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your big mistake is that you have flattened the grammar too much.  An expression grammar (that respects operator precedence<sup>1</sup>) will have separate productions for expression, and-expression, or-expression, relation and primary.

In a true recursive descent parser, your parse methods follow the shape of the grammar productions.  So a recursive descent parser shouldn't need to count left and right brackets.  The grammar / recursion should deal with that.

---

<sup>1 - I see that you intend your parser to produce an AST.  If the parser doesn't understand your language precedence rules, then the AST is liable to be incorrect for some examples.</sup>

---

> ... there aren't many SO questions on this topic.

Yes.  Because grammars and parsers are a complicated / advanced topic.  There is generally too much information to convey in a Stack Overflow Q&A format.  So most questions (e.g. "how do I write a parser for X?") end up being (rightly) closed as "needs more focus".

My recommendation is to *look for a good textbook* on parsers or compiler writing.  There is also some good introductory material in the documentation, etc for parser generator tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stephen C . Since then I've actually removed the parentheses counter, once we encounter a closer the node is simply returned. I agree I haven't went the traditional route, but would you say this is bad, considering there is no counting of anything and the recursion handles everything? This isn't for production or anything but is supposed to show my skills. I wonder if I should rewrite it to be more traditional or not

Comment: It is not really for me to say whether it is "good" or "bad" to not precisely mirror the grammar.  There could be pragmatic reasons for deviating ...  The only criteria that would (hypothetically) really matter are correctness and maintainability.